# HTML Table formatting Issue

Tags: html, perl, html-table, multiple-columns

I am trying to align contents of two arrays in a tabular format and send an email. But the second column in the table doesn't align as desired. The content of the second column appears as a single row.

I'm attaching output table as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Lite;
use HTML::Entities;

my $msg;
my @Sucess = qw(s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6);
my @Failed = qw(f1 f2 f3 f4);

my $html = '<table style="width:600px;margin:0 100px" border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">
    <thead><th bgcolor="#9fc0fb">Successful</th><th bgcolor="#9fc0fb">Failed</th></thead>
    <tbody>';    

$html .= "<tr><td>$_</td>" for @Sucess;
$html .= "<td>$_</td>" for @Failed;
$html .= " </tr>";


$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    from    => 'foo@abc.com',
    To      => 'foo@abc.com',
    Subject => 'Status of Update',
    Type    => 'multipart/related'
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => qq{
        <body>
        <html>$html</html>
        </body>
    },
);

MIME::Lite->send ('smtp','xyz.global.abc.com' );
$msg->send;
```

[image: Output Table]

Comment: soooo... you don't believe in closing tags? `</tbody></table>` :P

Comment: You are free to use whatever identifiers are valid in Perl, but people who are familiar with the language, and others who are unfamiliar with English, will thank you for using `snake_case` for local variables. An initial capital letter is a particular problem because the language itself reserves names like that for global identifiers such as package names. It doesn't look like you have a need to use `@Sucess` and `@Failed` over `@success` and `@failed`

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace your code that builds up the table with something that works in a logical order. HTML tables need to be defined row by row. You can't process all of the successes and then all of the failures.

I'd replace your middle section of code with something like this:

```
use List::Util qw[max];

my $max = max($#Sucess, $#Failed);

for (0 .. $max) {
  $html .= '<tr><td>';
  $html .= $Sucess[$_] // '';
  $html .= '</td><td>';
  $html .= $Failed[$_] // '';
  $html .= "</td></tr>\n";
}
```

But actually, I would never put raw HTML in a Perl program. Use a [templating system](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) instead.

Comment: The issue with *Template Toolkit* is that people see their dependencies and identifiers (primarily `class` strings) spread across multiple files, and it needs a very good IDE to keep track of them all. While it is quite possible to put the template into a program's `DATA` section, that approach is a little odd within a module, and it also provide for only one template per source file. That could be overcome clumsily using something like [Data::Section](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Section), but any less measures leave us struggling with multiple global identifiers

Comment: That doesn't sound like an issue with the Template Toolkit, it sounds like an issue with any templating engine. And, to be honest, in well over fifteen years of writing system using templates, yours is not a complaint I've ever heard before. Separating the display logic into a different file (or many files) is usually seen as an advantage of this approach. It allows people with different skillsets (front-end vs backend developers) to both work on their own part of the system independently.

Answer (score 1):

First you loop over each item in `@Sucess` and for each one you:

- Create a new row
- Create a cell in that row

> ```
> $html .= "<tr><td>$_</td>" for @Sucess;
> ```

Then you look over each item in `@Failed` and for each one you:

- Create a cell in the last row you created (for the most recent `@Sucess`)

> ```
> $html .= "<td>$_</td>" for @Failed;
> ```

Finally, you explicitly close the last table row you created:

> ```
> $html .= " </tr>";
> ```

---

To get the layout you desire (which is distinctly non-tabular) you need to work row by row. You can't deal with all the `@Sucess` and *then* all the `@Failed`.

```
my @Sucess= qw(s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6);
my @Failed= qw(f1 f2 f3 f4);

my $html = "<table>\n";

do {
    my $s = shift @Sucess;
    my $f = shift @Failed;
    $html .= sprintf("<tr> <td> %s </td> <td> %s </td> </tr> \n", map { $_ // '' } $s, $f);
} while ( @Sucess or @Failed );

$html .= "</table>";

print $html;
```